# One JSP file can't see the other

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I'm having some problems with forwarding from one JSP file to another .

At the beginning I'm in `adminSuccess.jsp` ,and I want to move to `adminPage.jsp` .

**Updated - Here is the hierarchy tree of the project  :**

[image]

And that's the code of **adminSuccess.jsp** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>System Administrator Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
<h1>
Please choose one of the following options
</h1>



<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new manager to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="adminAdds1"> 
    <a href="results/adminAddNewManager.jsp">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new employee to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="adminAdds2"> 
    <a href="results/adminAddNewEmployee.jsp">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

OUT:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /WebBank/results/adminAddNewManager.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /WebBank/results/adminAddNewManager.jsp

description The requested resource (/WebBank/results/adminAddNewManager.jsp) is not available.
```

Clearly , one jsp can't see the other, so how can I fix that , without taking out of the library one of the jsp files , since it would require change a lot of other code .

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources under WEB-INF are not publicly accessible resources if you want to access those you need to forward request from your servlet or JSP

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results/adminPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a little ?

Comment: It still doesn't work - I've updated the post , can you please take a look ? thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

Move your JSP files out of WEB-INF.

The issue is not that one JSP file can't 'see' another- you have a link containing a URL to a resource (i.e. a JSP file) that cannot be accessed directly  through a web browser (as resources in WEB-INF cannot be accessed in this way).

Comment: Problem continues even though that I moved the folder outside , please see the updated post .

Answer (score 0):

You've got a combination of good work and bad work in your code.

You put your JSPs inside `/WEB-INF/` which is good thing to do in an Model-2 application, it prevents direct access to JSPs.

But then you are trying access a JSP from another view without visiting the Servlet, which is not so good, and it's Model-1 (not suitable for big apps).